# Location not track properly using pubnub in Android

Tags: android, pubnub

I want to track a friends location using pubnub location tracker in a Google Map. Initially I have create the channel name and share my location with a friend. At the time of sharing the **lat** **long** value is correct, but after that the location is not shared properly. Instead, the current user location is shown on the map. I have posted the error response below.

How can I share and view my friends location?

```
public class PubNubManager {

    public final static String TAG = "PUBNUB";

    public static Pubnub startPubnub() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing PubNub");
        return new Pubnub("pub-c-3cfa8420-9dc7-4d03-a6b8-7a003537ed66", "sub-c-7ed859ba-4ef9-11e6-bfbb-02ee2ddab7fe");
    }

    public static void subscribe(Pubnub mPubnub, String channelName, Callback subscribeCallback) {
        // Subscribe to channel
        try {
            mPubnub.subscribe(channelName, subscribeCallback);
            Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to Channel");
        } catch (PubnubException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void broadcastLocation(Pubnub pubnub, String channelName, double latitude,
                                         double longitude, double altitude) {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        try {
            message.put("lat", latitude);
            message.put("lng", longitude);
            message.put("alt", altitude);
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending JSON Message: " + message.toString());
            pubnub.publish(channelName, message, publishCallback);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

    }

    public static Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
            Log.d("PUBNUB", "Sent Message: " + response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
            Log.d("PUBNUB", error.toString());
        }
    };
}
```

```
GMaps Share: Location Detected
07-25 17:57:22.460 12516-12516/io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker D/PUBNUB: Sending JSON Message: {"alt":1,"lng":78.1256751,"lat":9.9504371}
07-25 17:57:22.620 12516-12788/io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker D/PUBNUB: [Error: 129-0] : Page Not FoundPlease verify if network is reachable.Please contact support with error details. : []
```

`

Comment: What are you calling in your app that produces the error: `[Error: 129-0] : Page Not FoundPlease verify if network is reachable.Please contact support with error details.` And we are tracking this in private support with you and expecting to see your PubNub log files for the client that will allow us to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: i'm calling the broadcastLocation function that produce this error